# AWS Sagemaker pipeline creating throwing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker-studio

### I am newbie in using sagemaker pipeline .While following this AWS MLOPs workshop https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/741835d3-a2bf-4cb6-81f0-d0bb4a62edca/en-US/03-lab-03
I am getting error on notebook 3 at step 67 pipeline.upsert(role_arn=sm_role)
Below are the error msgs.

AttributeError: 'ParameterString' object has no attribute 'startswith'

TypeError: Pipeline variables do not support **str** operation. Please use `.to_string()` to convert it to string type in execution timeor use `.expr` to translate it to Json for display purpose in Python SDK.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AWS!

I had this same issue. It was fixed in the new version of the Python SDK a few weeks ago.

I had to create a new user in Studio (if you're in notebook instances, create a new notebook).

Then, replace this line

```
! pip install "sagemaker>=2.99.0"
```

with this one

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install 'sagemaker' --upgrade
```

Hope that helps!

This solution was taken from [joseproura](https://github.com/joseproura) on [this issue](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/3974), referencing [this bug fix](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/pull/3972).